Please explain the additional PEMDAS rules for rooting a negative?
In addition to the traditional rules of PEMDAS, there appear to be additional rules we must know when rooting a negative.  For instance, a well known example is:
$$
\sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt{1} = 1  
$$
versus
$$
\sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1} = i\cdot i = i^2 = -1
$$
using the rule $\sqrt{x\cdot y}= \sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{y}$.
My question is about using the following exponent rule:
$$
x^{mn} = (x^m)^n = (x^n)^m
$$
If $x$ is a negative number, the results appear to be inconsistent:
#1:  $(-1)^3 = -1$
#2:  $((-1)^2)^{3/2} = (1)^{3/2} = 1$
#3:  $((-1)^{3/2})^2 = (((-1)^{1/2})^3)^2 = (i^3)^2 = (-i)^2 = -1$
#4:  $((-1)^{3/2})^2 = (((-1)^3)^{1/2})^2 = ((-1)^{1/2})^2 = i^2 = -1$
Clearly, option #2 gives the wrong value, but why exactly?  What is the rule that specifies that the exponent rule
$$
x^{mn} = (x^m)^n = (x^n)^m 
$$
needs to be used more carefully when the base $(x)$ is negative?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Have you looked in some College Algebra or Precalculus texts? What about the text you learned from, presumably in high school? All such texts I've taught from, and even the Mary P. Dolciani texts used when I took school algebra and trigonometry, make the restriction that the base is positive when stating "the exponent rule" you're discussing: From p. 400 of the 1970 edition of Dolciani's Algebra $2$ and Trigonometry -- "Note that in extending powers to include all rational exponents, we have restricted the base $b$ to be a positive number. Without that restriction $\ldots$"

I meant to include a link to the quote I gave in my previous comment but forgot to do this. But since my comment was within a handful of characters from the maximum length, I would have needed a 2nd comment anyway. For p. 400 of Dolciani's 1970 edition of Modern School Mathematics. Algebra $2$ and Trigonometry at the Internet Archive, see here.

$\sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \cdot \cdot \cdot = -1$ care explaining? Logical sense implies $(-1)\cdot (-1) = 1$ and then proceed with solving the root. Your solution is true only when $-\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}$, negative sign being outside of the square root.

Oh my, thank you all!  Your clarifications make sense, and I can clearly see the incident that led me astray.... 15 years ago, there was a math software that claimed that the answer to sqrt((-1)(-1)) was -1, and it wouldn't let me proceed until I answered -1.  Now I see the software was wrong, and why!  It's never too late to fill a skill gap!!   Thank you :)

Shout out to Mary P. Dolciani!

Ahh, so here are some great clarifying examples that I found elsewhere:
x^(mn) = (x^m)^n  only when x > 0 and m,n real
Some absurd counterexamples:
e^i = (e^i)^(2pi/2pi) = (e^(i2pi))^(1/2pi) = 1^(1/2pi) = 1
and
(-1) = (-1)^(2/2) = ((-1)^2)^(1/2) = 1^(1/2) = 1

The additional "PEMDAS rules" you need for roots and exponents are as follows:

Whenever there are symbols inside a root symbol, the entire collection of symbols inside the root symbol is treated as if there were parentheses around it.

Whenever there are symbols at the upper right corner of an expression -- in the place where we expect to find exponents -- all of the symbols in that upper right corner, up to the next enclosing parenthesis (if there is one), are treated as if there were a set of parentheses around them.


So
$$ \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt{\Big((-1)(-1)\Big)} = \sqrt{1} , $$
$$ x^{mn} = x^{(mn)}, $$
but
$$\left(x^m\right)^n = \left(x^{(m)}\right)^{(n)}. $$
The rules that you have learned such as $x^{mn} = (x^m)^n = (x^n)^m$
and $\sqrt{xy} = \sqrt x\sqrt y$ have nothing to do with PEMDAS.
Those are rules of arithmetic that state that one expression evaluates to the same number as a different expression.
Let me add emphasis: a different expression.
The rules of arithmetic allow you, under very specific circumstances, to change the order of operations that you would apply if you only considered the PEMDAS conventions.
That is, they let you convert one expression into an entirely different expression such that PEMDAS dictates a different sequence of evaluation.
One such rule is the distributive law, for example, $(a + b)x = ax + bx$,
which lets you take a calculation where you had to add first and multiply last and instead multiply first and add last.
The rule $x^{mn} = \left(x^m\right)^n$ allows you to do exponentiation twice instead of multiplication first and then exponentiation. If we're working in real numbers, the rule is valid for positive $x$ and any numbers $m$ and $n$ or for integers $m$ and $n$ and any real number $x$, as well as a few other cases that are not really worth enumerating.
If you are working in complex numbers, you need to be clear how you handle roots and fractional exponents; in particular, what notation (if any) represents a principal root (which you must then define) and what notation (if any) represents a multifunction.

Just to be extra clear, the following are all true statements.
$$ \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = 1. $$
$$ \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} \neq - 1. $$
$$ \left((-1)^2\right)^{3/2} = 1. $$
$$ \left((-1)^2\right)^{3/2} \neq - 1. $$
Working in the real numbers, $\left((-1)^{3/2}\right)^2$ is undefined. You cannot evaluate $(-1)^{3/2}$ as a real number.
Working in the complex numbers, interpreting $z^{3/2}$ as
$\exp\left(\frac32 \ln z\right)$ where $\ln z$ returns the principal value of the logarithm of $z$ and the principal value of $\ln(-1)$ is $i\pi$,
$$
\left((-1)^{3/2}\right)^2
 = \left(\exp\left(\frac32 i\pi\right)\right)^2
 = (-i)^2 = -1.
$$
Other interpretations of complex exponentiation can give different results.
For example, you might consider $z^{3/2}$ as a multifunction, in which case it does not necessarily have a single unique numerical result.

Wow, thank you for this @David K.  So there are subtleties about how these expressions are evaluated, depending on if you're evaluating in the Reals or Complex.  Just to be extra thankful, I appreciate your help!!  :)

You're welcome! I hope I didn't scare you away from complex numbers with all those details, because complex numbers are an incredibly useful discovery of mathematics with many beautiful results. It's just that some of those results have consequences we would never have come across if we only used real numbers.
